# PLS-00103 when running script in APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to run the following PLSQL script in APEX:

```
DECLARE
    total NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO total
    FROM one_table;

    FOR i IN 0:100 --This is line 8
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO other_table(id, column_a) SELECT id + i * total, column_a FROM one_table;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

And I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 15: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following: * & - + / at mod remainder rem .. <an exponent (**)> || multiset The symbol ".." was substituted for "" to continue.'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is legal syntax:

```
FOR i IN 0:100
```

I think you mean:

```
FOR i IN 0..100
```